# IE document mode 8 or below is not compatible with .svg image type

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I have a document which has to be compatible with IE document mode 8. The html document has the following line

```
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

Now I have an .svg image which i Display using css file as follows,

```
background: url('../images/iPhoneAppStoreLogo.svg') no-repeat 0 0;
```

But this image is not displayed in IE Document mode 8 (Image is displayed in IE Document mode 9 and above). I have seen solution saying to increase the mode, but my application needs support IE Document mode 8 as well. So is there any solution for this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: [SVG is not supported in IE <= 8](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known that IE has some issues with `.svg`.
it's recommended to use a fallback while working with `.svg`
check this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-svg-fallbacks/), will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link, But the image i'm trying to display is the app store logo and for legal reasons i can only use that specific SVG image. So i cannot use it by changing the format or similar solutions. More info can be found here https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#downloadOnAppstore